# Rainfall Shower Head is Leaking

Tags: plumbing, shower, leak

I just installed a brand new rainfall shower head with a handheld attachment and I used what I believed were proper installation steps. Teflon tape was applied on every thread, washers were placed in every fitting. Regardless, there is a leak on the fitting where the arm attachment holding the shower head meets the 3-way diverter. The funny thing is that when I turn the knob to use the handheld attachment, the leak is pretty much gone. What gives??

[image]

Comment: The general rule is you either have a washer or teflon.  If there is a washer then you don't use teflon.

Comment: Properly applied teflon isn't going to cause problems the washer, and that leak doesn't seem to be coming from an installed connection.

Comment: "Properly applied" teflon tape often interfers with the seal of a washer or the metal to metal seal of valve seats. Thread sealant is only needed when the threads are the sealing barrier, e.g.,  pipe threads, tapered in the US and sometimes parallel elsewhere. As far as I can see none of these joints require teflon tape. What often happens is a piece of tape gets caught between the sealing washer and the end of the pipe.

Comment: In addition to not being needed, teflon tape detracts from the appearance of these designer fixtures.

Comment: The threads in these fittings provide a mechanical clamping force to press the end of a pipe into the sealing washer and to press the other side of the sealing washer onto a sealing surface. In these fittings water under pressure cannot get to the threads and so the threads do not need to be sealed.

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour] so you know how this site works.

Comment: What do the installation instructions say?

Answer (score 0):

That leak appear to be from internal issues in the arm to the rain head.

Return the product, noting it is defective.

If you were to take apart a factory assembly you will void the warranty.